# How do I create a blank desktop (on OS 10.7.5)

Tags: desktop, mission-control

I realize that this isn't a new feature but I've never needed to use different workspaces on my computer until now and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I'm able to add a new desktop by entering Mission Control and hovering over the translucent `+` that appears and clicking on it. My problem is that when I go to that newly-created space, it's a copy of the existing cluttered original desktop. How do I create a blank desktop?

Answer (score 3):

The point of spaces is that they allow for different collections and configurations of application windows, and they do not allow for having different desktops; the desktop is not a window.

The desktop icons shown are simply file and folder items at a file system level that are displayed without requiring to be viewed through an application window. There is only a single desktop folder per user.

Taking both of these into account, what you want can't work for a number of reasons

Answer (score 3):

I totally get it. And, 5 years later ... this is still not an option.

Regardless...

**As a solution, my approach was to do the following:**

1. move everything from the desktop into a folder
2. set that folder to display as icons
3. set that folder to hide the sidebar and toolbar
4. expand the folder to display fullscreen in it's own space

You could even go a step further and add alias's to your hard drive and then instruct the finder to hide it.
You can also set the background to use your desktop wallpaper to mirror what you are used to seeing on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via Mission Control - your desktop files are available on ALL desktops. The different desktops may only contain different open applications.

If you want a clean desktop, move the individual files where they make sense (or into the trash), or put them all in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the icon/program at the bottom of your screen that continues to reappear even when you change desktops.  Next, select options, then select "none" under assign to.  This will solve your problem